# IntelliJ IDEA says that the localhost port is already busy

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am new to intelij idea

I started debugging an application that was previously being written inside eclipse.

I configured the run configurations to startup tomcat and open chrome for the view.

However, after several runs the following happens:

1. the source files stop being updated
2. intelij claims localhost port is already busy

how do i stop the localhost run from intelij when the stop option (shift+f2) is grayed out
and how do i make the sources be updated.

it seems only a computer reboot fixes this problem right now
i obviously cant reboot my computer once every 10 minutes.

Comment: Try going to task manager and killing java process.

Answer (score 4):

If none of the above mentioned ways did not work for you, try this.

Open the Command Prompt and type following.

```
netstat -aon | find "1099"
```

If a process uses above port, it should return something output like this.

```
TCP    xxx.xx.xx.xx:1099      xx.xx.xx.xxx:443      ESTABLISHED     2222
```

The last column value (2222) is referred to the Process ID (**PID**).

Just **KILL** it as follows.

```
taskkill /F /PID 2222
```

Now start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

InteliJ claims localhost port is already busy => This means that the program that opened this listening port is still running. Now, it looks like you are starting the program from IntelliJ, but then it keeps running after IntelliJ disconnects from it. Do find if that is still the case.

Comment: IDEA opens new tabs for processes in the run and debug tool windows for each process one starts. Maybe there is a running process in another tab (while the stop option of the currently selected tab is inactive).

Answer (score 0):

If the necessary port (for tomcat 8080 for example) is busy outside of eclipse or IDEA, you can see use `Tcpview` application which shows which process which port use (you can just kill them if they are not so necessary). It seams files are read only, or IDEA don't recognize them as java files right click on source root and select **Murk Directory As**->**Source Root**. Try these steps and if you help more questions you are welcome.